# /tmp mounted with only 1MB space, 100% used, as filesystem "overflow"

Tags: ubuntu

For some reason, my `/tmp` is said to be 100% used.

```
root$ df 
Filesystem         1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on
overflow                1024        1024          0 100% /tmp
... other stuff ...
```

Output of running `df -h`

```
$ df -h
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1         102G   72G   25G  75% /
none              4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev              7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs             1.6G  844K  1.6G   1% /run
none              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none              7.8G  240K  7.8G   1% /run/shm
none              100M   16K  100M   1% /run/user
overflow          1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
```

Is there any way to safely remove unused stuff in `/tmp`?

Thanks

Comment: Your `/tmp` is only 1 MB? That's really not big enough.

Comment: Can you show the full `df -h`?  There may be more that can be read from this ..  ` ... other stuff ` is unhelpful.

Comment: Will update the question with more details

Comment: (sorry, why was my question closed?)

Answer (score 24):

This is bizarre, you should have a partition name like "/dev/sda4" instead of "overflow" in the first column of a df output associated with /tmp, or possibly no entry at all.... I've never seen this "overflow" before.

Googling "filesystem overflow tmp" found a bunch of similar cases.

The first link http://jarrodoverson.com/blog/overflow-filesystem-in-linux/
says

> If your “/tmp” mount on a linux filesystem is mounted as overflow
>   (often sized at 1MB), this is likely due to you not specifying “/tmp”
>   as its own partition and your root filesystem filled up and “/tmp” was
>   remounted as a fallback. To fix this after you’ve cleared space, just
>   unmount the fallback and it should remount at its original point:
>
> sudo umount overflow

Comment: If you get `device is busy` you can use `sudo umount -l overflow`

Comment: Thanks life saver comment.

Comment: Found after 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be able to look at the files in `/tmp`, and if 1) they are not open by any currently running process (see `fuser`, `lsof`, `pfiles`) and 2) not important to somebody, then you should be able to `rm` them. And (2) is questionable... If you remove people's stashed-in-the-wrong-place important files enough times, maybe they'll learn not to do that.

Oh, and definitely make `/tmp` bigger... It doesn't need to be huge, and there are good reasons to limit it, but `1M` is way too small. I can often get by with `64M`, but sometimes need `256M`.

Comment: I'm not sure which files are important and which aren't. So I'd rather not removing them... How do I make /tmp bigger, though?